# Another "why-does-it-boot-straight-to-windows8-after-installation-is-done" question

Tags: 14.04, uefi, boot-repair

Ok, I know that this has been asked a thousand times, but I've spent the last 5 hours trying to setup my Toshiba Satellite  to dual boot 14.04 and Win8.1 and I'm at the point where throwing the laptop off the window to test it's anti-gravity capabilities sounds like a pretty good idea.

So, to cut a long story short: Followed this guide: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) 
Fastboot is disabled. UEFI is enabled. LiveCD works as it should. Installation is complete. After restart laptop boots immediately to PC. Boot-repair returns this http://paste.ubuntu.com/10147575/ . I am nostalgic of the times before EFI. Ah the times we had, when a linux installation would take less than 45 minutes. Anyway, if anyone could offer any advice, I would owe them a great debt (not to mention my sanity)

Comment: Just an appeal to your nostalgia: EFI isn't the problem. It actually fixes many issues of legacy BIOS. The problem is Microsoft and the system assemblers prioritising a smooth Windows experience over freedom of choice for the users (and I'm not even going into the argument whether that's generally good or not).

Comment: Well, you're probably right, but the outcome is the same. I'm starting to wonder if there's another distro with a gentler installation process

Comment: I doubt there's gonna be "gentler" installation for any other distro, as it's the windows that's being a SOB. I'm gonna write an answer here, but there's no guarantee it's gonna work. Just try, see what happens, and keep yourself cool , friend, no need to loose never over resistant hardware

Comment: You have to select which OS to boot from your bios. see the troubleshooting section of the link you reference.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "freedom", it has to do with how many bios configure (uefi) boot .

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, there is no option in my bios to select which OS to boot. I only can choose between DVD-drive, Hd, USB and LAN. Possibly if I had a second HD that would solve the problem

Comment: GeMar - you need to find it in the EFi menu or if there is no option, update the bios and contact your vendor. It is sometimes hard to locate, it is NOT in the same section as DVD/HD/USB, usually it is the boot menu or security menu

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot  Live CD / Live USB, select try Ubuntu
2. Once it's loaded, open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
3. Do the following

`sudo mount  /dev/sda8   /mnt`

`sudo mount --bind /dev   /mnt/dev`

`sudo mount --bind /proc   /mnt/proc`

`sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys`

`sudo chroot /mnt`

NOTE: the `/dev/sda8` is your Ubuntu partition, from what I see in your pastebin file. Double check that with `lsblk` command, and see if you recognize that partition, and it has the right size

4. Do  `update-grub` and then `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`
5. Reboot

Try this, see what happens. Basically what we're doing here is installing grub on the boot sector of the hard drive, not just one partition `/dev/sda8`.

Comment: Note, --bind is two dashes and theres spaces between /dev/sda8 and /mnt. I suggest you type the code, instead of just copying it

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help. When i try the 
'sudo grub-install /dev/sda'
I get:
'sudo: unable to to resolve host ubuntu'
'Installing for x86_64-efi platform.'
'grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory'

Comment: Interesting. I think host ubuntu should be the name of the live usb, and your machine's actual host name should be username+machine name, eg Serg+Satellite+L455D. I've no clue, though. Um, maybe disable some of the "secure boot" settings or whatever. Sorry, I couldn't be much of help here

Comment: re-installing grub rarely helps

Comment: @bodhi.zazen , it's not reinstall, it's installation on the boot sector of the whole drive, unlike just one partition. My guess was that this way grub would bypass whatever was booting windows there, but i guess i was wrong

Comment: See this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported . Read the troubleshooting section "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP" - read on ...

Answer (score 0):

When you boot up hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. If Ubuntu installed correctly,  GRUB should load and give you options for which OS you want to start. Try and post results.

Comment: See this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported . Read the troubleshooting section "TROUBLESHOOTING

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP" - read on ...

Comment: Holding Shift after I select restart get's me to the windows menu with the light blue that allows me to boot into safe mode or into bios to change the UEFI. Holding Shift just when booting up does nothing, it still boots into win8.1 "normally@. Thanks for your time Anthony

Bodhi, I've done everything on the troubleshooting section and also followed this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI but to no avail. Thank you both for taking the time to answer